# How to add text before page number using tocloft?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, tocloft

I want to wrap the page number with parentheses like:

```
1.1 Section 1.1 ......... (1)
1.2 Section 1.2 ......... (5)
```

I found the `\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{)}` can add text after page number. But how to add text **before** page number?

Answer (score 1):

Use a redefined `\cftsecpagefont` for this, calling the old version after the `(` then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\origcftsecpagefont\cftsecpagefont
\let\origcftsecafterpnum\cftsecafterpnum

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{(\origcftsecpagefont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\origcftsecafterpnum)}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Section section}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

The `pnumwidth` might have to be adjusted for larger page numbers.

[image]